# Синхронизация с сервером

Tags: java, android

На сервере хранится расписание матчей. Мне необходимо, чтобы приложение посылало GET запрос на сервер каждый раз через определенный интервал и брало свежее расписание, даже если приложение не запущено (пользователь получит уведомление, если играет его команда), но интернет включен. Сервер возвращает расписание в формате json.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно действовать так:

1. Подписаться на запуск [девайса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20441442/3212712). Ловить это событие надо `BroadcastReceiver`-ом, прописанным в манифесте и подписанным на событие `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`. Также нужно соответствующее разрешение в манифесте.
2. В момент запуска девайса вам надо воспользоваться `AlarmManager`-ом для создания [периодически рассылаемого интента](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990/3212712) собственного, который будет каждые n-минут вызывать 2-ой `BroadcastReceiver`
3. Действия из второго пункта также надо совершить при запуске приложения. Иначе ваши интенты не будут зарегистрированы в системе пока вы не перезапустите девайс.
4. Во втором `BroadcastReceiver`, запускаемом при рассылке ваших собственных интентов вам надо запустить `IntentService` в котором и сделать запрос на сервер и вывести, если нужно, уведомление

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд для такого кейса нужно не запрос через определенный интервал времени слать, а с сервера push уведомление слать через Firebase cloud message. Это настраивается довольно просто.